# Difference between }; and } in C++

Tags: c++, methods

brand new to C++.

Woking on a project for an assignment, and in some example code I have found methods ending with }; instead of the typical (expected) }

For example:

```
CircBuffer::CircBuffer()
{
    cout<<"constructor called\n";
    cout<<"Buffer has " << BufferSize << "elements\n";

    for (int i = 0; i<= BufferSize -1; i++)
    {
        Buffer[i] = 0;
    }

    ReadIn = WriteIn = 0;
    setDelay(0);

}; // <=== HERE
```

I can't find any information as to why this would be done online.

Thanks, Lewis

Comment: it's an empty statement.

only type definitions require the semicolon: `class A { ... };` functions do not

Comment: An empty statement it is.it is like saying "do not execute any statement in this line"

Comment: It's likely a typo

Comment: @BeyelerStudios: This is not an "empty statement". C++ does not allow one to write statements in namespace scope. It is an *empty declaration*, which is a completely different thing.

Comment: @AndreyT you're right

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That trailing `;` in namespace scope constitutes an *empty declaration*. What you have in the above code is seen by the compiler as

```
CircBuffer::CircBuffer()
{
  ...
}      // <- the `CircBuffer::CircBuffer` definition ends here

;      // <- an empty declaration that declares nothing
```

I.e. the method definition does not really end with `};` from the compiler's point of view. It ends with `}`, and the `;` is treated completely separately and independently.

Empty declaration was illegal in the original version of C++ and in C++03, but it was legalized in C++11. The code you quoted above is therefore invalid in C++98 and C++03, but legal in C++11. However, even C++98 compilers often supported empty declarations as a non-standard extension.

Note that the above applies only to out-of-class function definitions (as in your example). With in-class member function definitions the trailing `;` has always been legal (and optional)

```
class C
{
  C()
  {
    ...
  }; // <- ';' not required, but legal even in C++98
};
```

(In this case the optional `;` is actually a part of member definition, meaning that the definition does indeed end in `};` and does not introduce an empty declaration.)

When you see something like that in the actual code, it is probably just a bad habit, maybe based on the confusion between the in-class and out-of-class definition contexts.

Comment: Also note that the semicolon after the closing `class C` brace is *not* optional.

Answer (score 1):

Could be for consistency or it could be a reminiscent of old code, for example if the original was just a declaration:

```
CircBuffer::CircBuffer();
```

and someone wanted to add an inline implementation, he might have clicked before the trailing `;` and started writing the body there, forgetting to remove the `;`.